# SOLR Data Input Handler ( DIH ) : extract email addresses during indexing and put in another field ?

Tags: solr, extract, dih, reindex

I have a field called main_text which contains a large text entries .

I want to reindex my data, by creating a new collection , but I want to extract all email addresses from this field to new special field called emails_fields.

What will be the best way to do it ?

What handler to use ? DIH  ? another ? 
what type should be this new field ?

Answer (score 0):

To use the DataImportHandler you should add something similar to the following to your `data-config.xml` file.

```
<field column="email_fields" regex="(/S+@/S+)" sourceColName="main_text"/>
```

This would look for email addresses that match the regex `/S+@/S+`. This regular expression should be changed to something better for real use.

The type of the field depends on how you want to search it but it should probably be `string` or `text_general` and if you are expecting there to be more than one email in each document it should be multi-valued.

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to add this line to data-config.xml

Comment: Could you explain more as to why it is not possible? Do you not have access to the file?